# npm copy file to a shared drive

Tags: npm

Is it possible to copy app.js (from dist folder) to a shared drive (inside my organization)? a scripts setting inside Package.json

npm install copy-files-from-to is a good add-on but doesn't copy to a shared drive. I tried fetching a file from a shared drive as it works well but the other way doesn't seem to work.

Here is a copy of the json file:

```
{ "copyFiles": [ { "from": "dist/js/app.js", "to": "\\\\<Shared Path>\\app.js" } ] }
```

Comment: {
    "copyFiles": [
  {
   "from": "dist/js/app.js",
   "to": "\\\\<Shared Path>\\app.js"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Above is a copy of the .json file